# scoping issue with updateNavbarPage() function from within shiny module

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am trying to build an app where the user is able to switch tabs when clicking on a specific object. However, I have developed the app using modules and would like to continue to do so. I am running into a problem with the scoping when trying to call the `updateNavbarPage()` function from inside of the modules. I have created a MWE example to illustrate the problem.

```
#==================================================
# MRE for updateNavBar scoping issue within modules
#==================================================

modOneUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    h4(
      "Click this button to change tabs!"
    ),
    actionButton(
      ns("submit"),
      label = "Go to next Tab"
    )
  )
}


modOne <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    updateNavbarPage(session, "nav-page", "tab2")
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    id = "nav-page",
    title = "Example Navbar Page Issue",
    tabPanel(
      id = "tab1",
      value = "tab1",
      div(
        "Tab 1"
      ),
      div(
        modOneUI("tab1_mod")
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      id = "tab2",
      value = "tab2",
      div(
        "Tab 2"
      ), 
      div(
        h4("This is the second tab")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  callModule(modOne, "tab1_mod")

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When this app is run, and the action button is clicked on the first tab, nothing happens. However if you remove the module and place the ui and server module code directly into the ui and server portions then clicking the button works. Here is the code with the modules removed.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    id = "nav-page",
    title = "Example Navbar Page Issue",
    tabPanel(
      id = "tab1",
      value = "tab1",
      div(
        "Tab 1"
      ),
      div(
        h4(
          "Click this button to change tabs!"
        ),
        actionButton(
          "submit",
          label = "Go to next Tab"
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      id = "tab2",
      value = "tab2",
      div(
        "Tab 2"
      ), 
      div(
        h4("This is the second tab")
     )
    )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    updateNavbarPage(session, "nav-page", "tab2")
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there any way to use `updateNavbarPage()` from within a module to switch to a tab that is in not in the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not ask me why :-) but it works like this:

```
modOne <- function(input, output, session, x){
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    updateNavbarPage(x, "nav-page", "tab2")
  })
}
callModule(modOne, "tab1_mod", x=session)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like strange behaviour, but it certainly fixes my problem for me!